# DropWizard Auth by Example

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, basic-authentication, dropwizard

I'm trying to understand how authentication and authorization work in [DropWizard](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/index.html). I've read their [auth guide](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/auth.html) as well as the [dropwizard-security](https://github.com/stevenalexander/dropwizard-security) project on GitHub, but feel like I'm still missing a few important concepts.

```
public class SimpleCredential {
    private String password;

    public SimpleCredential(String password) {
        super();

        this.password = password;
    }
}

public class SimplePrincipal {
    pivate String username;

    public SimplePrincipal(String username) {
        super();

        this.username = username;
    }
}

public class SimpleAuthenticator implements Authenticator<SimpleCredential, SimplePrincipal> {
    @Override
    public Optional<SimplePrincipal> authenticate(SimpleCredential credential) throws AuthenticationException {
        if(!"12345".equals(credential.getPassword())) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Sign in failed.");
        }

        Optional.fromNullable(new SimplePrincipal("simple_user"));
    }
}
```

And then in my `Application` subclass:

```
@Override
public void run(BackendConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.jersey().register(new BasicAuthProvider<SimplePrincipal>(new SimpleAuthenticator(), "SUPER SECRET STUFF"));
}
```

And then in a resource method:

```
@GET
@Path("address/{address_id}")
@Override
public Address getAddress(@Auth @PathParam("address_id") Long id) {
    addressDao.getAddressById(id);
}
```

I think I have this half-configured correctly for basic auth, but not understanding the role that `SimpleCredential` and `SimplePrincipal` play. Specifically:

1. How do I set basic auth username/password from the Jersey/JAX-RS client?
2. What role do `SimpleCredential` and `SimplePrincipal` play with basic auth? Do I need to add anything to them or other classes to make basic auth work such that the only valid username is `simple_user` and the only valid password is `12345`?
3. How do I enforce access/authroization/roles via `SimplePrincipal`? Or is the concept of authorization non-existent with web services?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Question 1:

[Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) protocol states the client request should have a header in the form of

```
Authorization: Basic Base64Encoded(username:password)
```

where `Base64Encoded(username:password)` is an actual Base64 encoded string of the `username:password`. For example, if my username and password are `peeskillet:pass`, the header should be sent out as

```
Authorization: Basic cGVlc2tpbGxldDpwYXNz
```

That being said, the Jersey Client (assuming 1.x) has an `HTTPBasicAuthFilter`, which is a client side filter, that will handle the encoding part for us. So the client side request might look something like

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource(BASE_URI);
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("peeskillet", "pass"));
String response = resource.get(String.class);
```

That's all we would need to make a simple GET request with the authorization header.

### Question 2:

**SimpleCredential:** For Basic auth, we would actually be required to use `BasicCredentials`, instead of our own credentials. Basically, the request will go through the `BasicAuthProvider`. The provider will parse the Authorization header and create a `BasicCredentials` object from the parsed username and password.  Once that processing has finished, the `BasicCredentials` will get passed to our `SimpleAuthenticator`'s. We use those credentials to authenticate the user.

**SimplePrincipal:** is basically what we will use to *authorize* the client. From the authentication process, we can build a principal, that will be used to authorize later (see Question 3). So an example might look something like

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthenticationException;
import io.dropwizard.auth.Authenticator;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentials;

public class SimpleAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials,
                                                          SimplePrincipal> {
    @Override
    public Optional<SimplePrincipal> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        // Note: this is horrible authentication. Normally we'd use some
        // service to identify the password from the user name.
        if (!"pass".equals(credentials.getPassword())) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Boo Hooo!");
        }

        // from some user service get the roles for this user
        // I am explicitly setting it just for simplicity
        SimplePrincipal prince = new SimplePrincipal(credentials.getUsername());
        prince.getRoles().add(Roles.ADMIN);

        return Optional.fromNullable(prince);
    }
}
```

I altered the `SimplePrincipal` class a bit, and created a simple `Roles` class.

```
public class SimplePrincipal {

    private String username;
    private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public SimplePrincipal(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public boolean isUserInRole(String roleToCheck) {
        return roles.contains(roleToCheck);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}

public class Roles {
    public static final String USER = "USER";
    public static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    public static final String EMPLOYEE = "EMPLOYEE";
}
```

### Question 3:

Some might prefer to have an extra filter layer for authorization, but Dropwizard appears to have the opinionated view that the authorization should occur in the resource class (I forgot exactly where I read it, but I *believe* their argument is testability). What happens with the `SimplePrincial` that we created in the `SimpleAuthenticator` is that it can be injected into our resource method, with the use of the `@Auth` annotations. We can use the `SimplePrincipal` to authorize. Something like

```
import dropwizard.sample.helloworld.security.Roles;
import dropwizard.sample.helloworld.security.SimplePrincipal;
import io.dropwizard.auth.Auth;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/simple")
public class SimpleResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getResponse(@Auth SimplePrincipal principal) {
        if (!principal.isUserInRole(Roles.ADMIN)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
        }
        return Response.ok(
                "{\"Hello\": \"" + principal.getUsername() + "\"}").build();
    }
}
```

---

So putting it all together, with this configuration

```
environment.jersey().register(new BasicAuthProvider<SimplePrincipal>(
                                            new SimpleAuthenticator(), 
                                            "Basic Example Realm")
);
```

and the client credentials I posted previously, when we make the request, we should get a returned

```
{"Hello": "peeskillet"}
```

---

Also it should be mentioned that Basic auth alone is not secure, and it is recommended to be done over SSL

---

**See Related:**

- [DropWizard Auth Realms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431182/2587435)
- [SSL with DropWizard](http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#ssl)

---

### UPDATE

A couple things:

- For Dropwizard 0.8.x, the configuration of Basic Auth has changed a bit. You can see [**more here**](http://www.dropwizard.io/manual/auth.html). A simple example would be

  ```
  SimpleAuthenticator auth = new SimpleAuthenticator();
  env.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(
          new BasicAuthFactory<>(auth,"Example Realm",SimplePrincipal.class)));
  ```
- See above link for recommended usage of `AuthenticationException`

Comment: Thanks for such an amazing answer @peeskillet (+1)! A few followup questions, since you piqued my interests: (1) When I inject principals into my resource methods, I assume that this method works with Basic Auth as well as any other auth system I choose to use (OAuthv2, something custom, etc.), yes? (2) I also assume that I can have other arguments in my resource methods, so borrowing from your example above, could I have `public Response getResponse(@Auth SimplePrincipal prince, @PathParam("id") Long id)`, yes?

Comment: And (3) if I wanted to create my own API key-based auth system (evenutally, not now when I'm a newbie), can you offer any suggestions as to how I could inject that API key from the client side, and how I could extract ann API key out of a request from the server-side? With Basic Auth, as your example shows, I just add a `HttpBasicAuthFilter` to my Jersey client, and then register a `BasicAuthProvider` with DropWizard. What might this look like for a API key solution where, say, the client passes a String of `"128347847"` as their API key? Thanks again, and as always, you're my hero!

Comment: (1) Oauth - Seems to be the case; Custom - Depends on the implementation (2) Yes (3) Depends on the implementation. I've seen something as simple as a sending the key in the query string, to more complicated cases with SSL/secret key/timed token solutions. If you want a real answer, then I would need to know what is the plan of attack.

Comment: Thanks again @peeskillet (+1) - when I get to that point I'll post a question about a custom, API-key based client-side solution if I need to.

Comment: "more here" link is expired!! :|