# DropWizard Auth Realms

Tags: java, authentication, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

In DropWizard, I can set up basic auth like so (in the `Application#run` impl):

```
BasicAuthProvider<SimplePrincipal> authProvider = new BasicAuthProvider(authenticator, "SECRET_REALM");
environment.jersey().register(authProvider);
```

I am wondering what the significance of the String `realm` ("*SECRET_REALM*") is?

From general security concepts, I understand a "realm" to be a place (database, directory, file, keystore, etc.) where users and roles/permissions are stored.

What does a realm mean in DropWizard, and what's the significance of specifying it inside `BasicAuthProvider`? Does it create something with this realm under the hood?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A realm is in a sense, some protected area/space in the server. The realm should have a name.  If we run the example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393546/2587435), using [**cURL**](http://curl.haxx.se/)(which I recommend downloading, as it's useful in development), without any user credentials, we will see the following.

```
C:\>curl -i  http://localhost:8080/simple
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 18:55:02 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Basic Example Realm"
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Credentials are required to access this resource.
```

This is how the [Basic Auth Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol) works. When the server want the user agent to authenticate, to access a secured resource, it will send back a "401 Unauthorized", along with the header similar to

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Basic Example Realm"
```

The name you provide to the `BasicAuthProvider` is the `realm` that will be provided in the header. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/blob/master/dropwizard-java8-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/java8/auth/basic/BasicAuthProvider.java)

```
if (required) {
    final String challenge = String.format(CHALLENGE_FORMAT, realm);
    throw new WebApplicationException(
                                    Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, challenge)
                    .entity("Credentials are required to access this resource.")
                    .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                    .build());
```

Now try to access the resource from the browser. You will see

[image]

You can also see the realm name there. The [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.1) just states (about the `realm`):

> realm:
> A string to be displayed to users so they know which username and
> password to use. This string should contain at least the name of
> the host performing the authentication and might additionally
> indicate the collection of users who might have access. An example
> might be "registered_users@gotham.news.com".

Comment: Once again, thanks @peeskillet (+1)! I have posted **a lot** of questions on SO, and you are by far the most thorough, responsive & helpful user I've come across here. Thanks again!