# Authentication in a RESTful web service - Java and Elasticsearch - HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: java, rest, authentication, authorization

I am trying to write a RESTful web service in Java 8. I'm using Glassfish (Jersey and Grizzly)

Let's take the user resource.

```
http://localhost:8080/geocon/users
```

After I mapped the *HTTP Verbs*, I realised that, without a proper login strategy, everyone who knows an user ID (in this example I took 007 as userId) could call a **DELETE** to

```
http://localhost:8080/geocon/users/007
```

actually deleting the user with ID 007. Same as **PUT** verb, where anyone could overwrite old data with new - without any authorization. I am using Elasticsearch for storing users (and other types of resource) as JSON documents and I was wondering if I could still use it for storing password informations.

Considered that I don't mind using the basic HTTP authentication mechanism, **how do I do it in practice? How could I check if an user is actually himself and has the permission to delete or refresh data refering to him?** Thanks

Comment: So basically I created another Elasticsearch type called "credentials" where are stored JSON with id and password inside. Now the thing is, I would like to use the basic http mechanism for sending user and password every time I "query" the web service. How?

Comment: Check out some of the links [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28271760/2587435). There's a link to the Java EE tutorial for implementing security in a webapp. There's also a link to a self-implementation of Basic Auth in a Jersy application.