# Return locked user in dropwizard auth

Tags: dropwizard

In `dropwizard auth` module, I want to return to the caller of my rest-api that the user is **locked**.

(the credentials might be correct, but the user is locked/disabled)

I've looked here: http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/manual/auth.html but cannot find anything related to it.

And `authenticate` method of `Authenticator` returns Optional of my `T` object, and the documentation says:

> You should only throw an AuthenticationException if the authenticator
>   is unable to check the credentials (e.g., your database is down).

Comment: couldn't you just create a standard-inactive-user and return this user instead? alternatively, you could create a basic role system as stated in the docs and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392224/dropwizard-auth-by-example and create a role "disabled", nor?

Comment: Both seems to me as workarounds, thanks for suggestions. does this means that DW doesn't provide a solution for this requirement?

As in both cases, the user when tries to access a resource and instead of getting `401`, he will got `403`. because he will be a valid logged-in user with not permissions, and this is not the case. he should be treated as still-not-logged-in user who should always got `401` errors.

Comment: I believe DW does not want you to throw any other exception because the auth handler does not handle that. You can certainly throw your own exception and have a handler that returns the correct response for your particular usecase. What they want to avoid is the authentication returning a 500 error on wrong auth. Alternatively, write your own auth filter.

Comment: @pandaadb I don't want to throw an exception here, i just need to tell the client user is locked. Btw can you provide a link in how to customize auth handler?

Comment: If you throw a custom exception and you handle the exception with an exceptionmapper then you could throw ClientUserLockedException() which the handler could translate to a 4XX response code (whichever one you want)

Answer (score 0):

so, for some background, the reason you should only throw an `AuthenticationException` is because the filter provided by the good guys at DW only handles this exception. For all other exceptions, this is undefined.

For detail see: `AuthFilter#authenticate`

However, there is a really easy way to do what you want.

Looking at the DW code, you get this:

```
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        final BasicCredentials credentials =
                getCredentials(requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
        if (!authenticate(requestContext, credentials, SecurityContext.BASIC_AUTH)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(unauthorizedHandler.buildResponse(prefix, realm));
        }
    }
```

What this code does is to call your `Authenticator` to resolve the user and then check if it is authenticated. If it is not, then it will call the `UnauthorizedHandler` to check out what response it needs. Sadly, the handler does not get the Principal passed in, so it can only return a static exception.

Now, if you wanted to hand-craft this, this would be your entrypoint. Instead of simply using the `BasicCredentialAuthFilter` they provide, you would write your own that does the right thing for you.

However, from the code snippet, we can see that all this filter does is to throw a `WebApplicationException`. So we can shortcut this.

Our `Authenticator` implementation can do the user-locked check beforehand and populate an exception for us to bypass this behaviour. This way, the downstream logic is preserved (react to the `WebapplicationException` which I believe is actually a jersey feautere (see: exception mapppers)).

So, consider this example:

```
public class AuthenticatorTest extends io.dropwizard.Application<Configuration> {
    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        environment.jersey().register(new MyHelloResource());
        UserAuth a = new UserAuth();
        environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<Principal>()
                .setAuthenticator(a).setRealm("SUPER SECRET STUFF").buildAuthFilter()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new AuthenticatorTest().run("server", "/home/artur/dev/repo/sandbox/src/main/resources/config/test.yaml");
    }

    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class MyHelloResource {

        @GET
        @Path("asd")
        @PermitAll
        public String test(String x) {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }

    public static class UserAuth implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, Principal> {
        @Override
        public Optional<Principal> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(403).entity("User is blocked").build());
        }
    }

}
```

This code simply creates a new exception instead of authenticating the username. This results in this curl:

```
artur@pandaadb:/$ curl "artur:artur@localhost:9085/api/test/asd"
User is blockedartur@pandaadb:/$ curl "artur:artur@localhost:9085/api/test/asd" -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9085 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'artur'
> GET /api/test/asd HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9085
> Authorization: Basic YXJ0dXI6YXJ0dXI=
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 14:19:27 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 15
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
User is blocked
```

Now, this is likely not the cleanest solution that you can do. If you need this to be quick, then you can just throw the exception out of the `Authenticator`. However, the correct approach would be:

1. Implement a new AuthFilter basing it off `io.dropwizard.auth.AuthFilter`
2. Overwrite the authenticate method on `AuthFilter` to check your user and throw the correct exception there.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable answer, do you think we should return 401 instead in this case?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. 401 - unauthorized, if "locked user" means that it is unauthorized, then probably 401 is correct here.