# Dropwizard Authentication with POST calls failing

Tags: authentication, jersey, dropwizard

I was trying out Dropwizard authentication in my code but facing some issue in POST call at runtime, although its working fine with GET. this is how I am using this in the GET call:

```
@Override
@GET
@Path("/auth")
public Response doAuth(@Auth User user) {
    //do something
}
```

And then in Post call which is not working:

```
@Override
@POST
@Path("/")
public Response createLegalEntity(@Auth User user, LegalEntity createLegalEntity) {
    // do something
}
```

While running it is throwing following error:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.flipkart.api.LegalEntityResource.createLegalEntity(com.yammer.dropwizard.authenticator.User,org.flipkart.model.LegalEntity) at parameter at index 0
```

I am new to Dropwizard and not able to figure out the cause of the problem.

**UPDATE**

Here is how I have registered my ldap authentication configs:

```
 final LdapConfiguration ldapConfiguration = configuration.getLdapConfiguration();
    Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> ldapAuthenticator = new CachingAuthenticator<>(
            environment.metrics(),
            new ResourceAuthenticator(new LdapAuthenticator(ldapConfiguration)),
            ldapConfiguration.getCachePolicy());

    environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(
            new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                    .setAuthenticator(ldapAuthenticator)
                    .setRealm("LDAP")
                    .buildAuthFilter()));

    environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that you have not configured that auth feature correctly. The one thing that most people forget about is the `AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder`. An instance of this class also needs to be registed. This would definitely cause the error you are seeing, if unregistered.

```
// If you want to use @Auth to inject a custom Principal type into your resource

environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
```

<sup>From [Basic Authentication docs](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.0/docs/manual/auth.html#basic-authentication)</sup>

**See also:**

- [My comment](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1115#issuecomment-191693809) for Dropwizard issue regarding the same problem. You will get a good explanation of the what causes the problem.

Comment: Nice explanation, now I know how resources are initialised, but the problem is, I have already registered AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder in my code, still this problem is occurring, Please check  my update on the question

Comment: Is this a runtime (on request) error or startup error? If the former, I think I was wrong in my assumption.  If it was a startup error, it would be a ModelValidationException. But it looks like the error is happening on request, as it can't find an object to inject. In which case, make sure you're actually returning a User from the authenticator. That's the only think I can think of that would can this error at runtime

Comment: it is actually a start up error, but there is no ModelValidationException in the stacktrace, please check the logs https://justpaste.it/15luy

Comment: So looking at the stacktrace, it looks like you're using Jersey 1.x, which is Dropwizard <= 0.7.x. The auth configuration you have is for Dw >= 0.8.x, which is Jersey 2.x These version are incompatible. You can check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392224/dropwizard-auth-by-example/27393546#27393546) for the 0.7 configuration. It's really only a one-liner

Comment: If it's a new project you're working on, I would suggest you switch to the newest Dw version, which is 1.1.0. See the [getting started](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.0/docs/getting-started.html)